# Loop through text file with sections

Tags: ruby, loops, text, each

I have a file with about 11000 lines. Its built up like this:

```
some info 1
some cool info 1
some other info 1
foo bar 1


some info 2
some cool info 2
some other info 2
foo bar 2
```

I would like to set up a loop to go through this, and do like:

```
data1 = line1
data2 = line2
data3 = line3
data4 = line4
# do stuff with the data 1,2,3,4
data1 = line7
data2 = line8
data3 = line9
data4 = line10
# do stuff with the data 1,2,3,4
```

and do this for all the stuff in the text file. Anybody has any ideas? This is fine to do manually for ten lines, but when its about 11000 lines, I rather have it done automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.open('/tmp/lines', 'r').each_slice(6) do |group|
  # remove newlines
  group.map! {|item| item.chomp }

  data1, data2, data3, data4 = group

  # do something with the variables...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) on your `File` object will do the job just perfectly. This doesn't take empty lines into consideration though, but there's a nice trick to handle that in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

```
input = <<-EOF
some info 1
some cool info 1
some other info 1
foo bar 1



some info 2
some cool info 2
some other info 2
foo bar 2
EOF

input.lines.reject(&:empty?).each_slice(4) do |data|
  puts data[0]
  puts data[1]
  puts data[2]
  puts data[3]
  puts '-----'
end
```

output:

```
some info 1
some cool info 1
some other info 1
foo bar 1
-----
some info 2
some cool info 2
some other info 2
foo bar 2
-----
```